# Pseudo element stopping event click

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am customizing select box by using css *:after* Attribute.

Html:

```html
<div class="styled">
    <select>
        <option>India, Rupees (Rs.)</option>
        <option>USA, Dollars ($) </option>
        <option>United Kingdom, Pounds (&#163;)</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

css:

```css
div.styled{

    display: inline-block;

    float: left;

    position: relative;

    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;

    border-radius: 3px;

    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ddd;

}
.styled select option{

    padding: 5px;

}

div.styled:after{

    content: "";

    background: #fff url("dn_arw.png") no-repeat 2px 4px; 

    display: inline-block;

    float: left;

    height: 18px;

    position: absolute;

    right: 8px;

    top: 6px;

    width: 15px;

}
```

The below is the image and js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CtYnt/

The Problem is the area which is overlapped with "down arrow image" is not clickable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To [make it work](http://jsfiddle.net/nPQkq/) in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, you can use one line of CSS in the `:after` block:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

IE takes more work, the easiest way is to use conditional statement for IE on the `:after` block and set:

```
display:none;
```

Alternatively if your overlayed DIV MUST work in IE, there is a hack [detailed here](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/).

Comment: @ManiKumarAkasapu - Glad I could help, had the same issue a while back.